# Android attach drawable to last item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, drawable, footer

Without going into details, I need to attach a drawable at the bottom of last item in ListView. The limitation is I can only use styles & themes to achieve it. No Java code is allowed. I also can't add any item to the end of the adapter.

How can I do it? All hacks are welcome. Thanks!

*Added: Or maybe it's possible to attach footerview to the listview via xml?*

Comment: Details are little things that could make the difference between an answered question and an unanswered one. Are you looking to attach the drawable to the last item of the `ListView` or  just **below** the `ListView`'s last element? (Is this related to your rounded corners `ListView` question?)

Comment: Use relative layout and add the drawable to the XML giving it the `layout_below=@id/ListviewID`

Comment: @Luksprog: It should be attached just below the last item. It doesn't make difference for me whether it's achieved using the actual list item or the ListView, as long as it's done using just styles & themes. As far as I remember we can adjust only the selector via the styles, so it would be hard to access the last item. But maybe perhaps we can attach that extra drawable to every item, but the item under will hide it so it will be visible only at the end?

Comment: @Urban: Impossible, I can only edit styles & themes.

Comment: @SebastianNowak I doubt that what you're trying to do is possible with just styles and themes. Trying to modify the rows I don't think it will work because with styles you can't differentiate between rows(the last one from the others). If this is related to your last questions then I advise you to take another approach instead of imposing a only themes solution(which will not work).

Comment: @SebastianNowak: 1. set list-item view's style to be transparent, 2. set ListView's background to drawable aligned to bottom :) - solves your case? ;)

Comment: No, because it doesn't scroll with the content and is aligned at the bottom of ListView, not just below the last item. Thanks anyway.